# RegEx for matching the first {N} chars and last {M} chars

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm having an issue filtering tags in Grafana with an InfluxDB backend. I'm trying to filter out the first 8 characters and last 2 of the tag but I'm running into a really weird issue.

Here are some of the names...

> - GYPSKSVLMP2L1HBS135WH
> - GYPSKSVLMP2L2HBS135WH
> - RSHLKSVLMP1L1HBS045RD
> - RSHLKSVLMP35L1HBS135WH
> - RSHLKSVLMP35L2HBS135WH

only want to return something like this:

> - MP8L1HBS225
> - MP24L2HBS045

I first started off using this expression:

> [MP].*

But it only returns the following out of 148:

> - PAYNKSVLMP27L1HBS045RD
> - PAYNKSVLMP27L1HBS135WH
> - PAYNKSVLMP27L1HBS225BL
> - PAYNKSVLMP27L1HBS315BR

Comment: Questions that ask ["Give me a regex that does X"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733) with no attempt are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What language are you using. The way you describe it I can't see any reason to use regex at all. It's basic string handling.

Comment: @kvantor - How is this Off-Topic. I have a legit question and I'm a total noob with regex expressions. Grafana requires that I use them to achieve what I'm trying to do.

@ Andreas - honestly, I'm not sure. It's part of the variables section in Grafana.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `[MP].*` Matches either a M or P and then matches any char until the end of the string not taking any char, digit or quantifing number afterwards into account.

If you want to match `MP` and the value does not end on a digit but the last in the match should be a digit, you could use:

```
MP[A-Z0-9]+[0-9]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtCs7M/3)

If lookaheads are supported you might also use:

```
MP[A-Z0-9]+(?=[A-Z0-9]{2}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtCs7M/2)

Answer (score 1):

You may not even want to touch MP. You can simply define a left and right boundary, just like your question asks, and swipe everything in between which might be faster, maybe [an expression](https://regex101.com/r/mlYJ0V/1) similar to:

```
 (\w{8})(.*)(\w{2})
```

which you can simply call it using `$2`. That is the second capturing group, just to be easy to replace.

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work: 
[image]

#### Performance

This JavaScript snippet shows the performance of this expression using a simple 1-million times `for` loop.

```js
repeat = 1000000;
start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = "RSHLKSVLMP35L2HBS135WH";
 var regex = /^(\w{8})(.*)(\w{2})$/g;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "$2");
}

end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

Comment: Emma, thank you. I couldn't seem to figure out how regex breaks groups like that.

Comment: I'm thinking I need to submit a bug report for their implementation of regex in Grafana. This was my result

AGSTKSVL
BNTNKSVL
BRNOKSVL
DGLSKSVL
GYPSKSVL
PAYNKSVL
RCKFKSVL
RSHLKSVL
SPNGKSVL
TWNDKSVL

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=\w{8})\w+(?=\w{2})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aUQVmY/1)

Comment: I'm thinking I need to submit a bug report for their implementation of regex in Grafana. I tried yours and it didn't return a thing. Regex101 shows that it works perfectly though.